# How to automatically call Entity Framework's update from database without Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, compiler-construction

I have a WCF Data Service service that uses Entity Framework to provide data. When the database changes, I have to use the EDMX editor of Visual Studio to call Update from database to match the data classes.
Is it possible to call a *csc* compiling together with an update from the database first? I'd like to avoid the dependency of using VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, code generation is possible using a command-line tool.
Have a look at the [edmgen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387165.aspx) page.

Comment: It is close to what I'm looking for, but it has limitations (can't specify tables) and says nothing about updating, only generating. _A conceptual model generated by EdmGen.exe includes all the objects in the database. If you want to generate a conceptual model that includes only specific objects, use the Entity Data Model Wizard. For more information, see How to: Use the Entity Data Model Wizard._

Comment: I see. Searching a bit, i saw another tool called edmgen2.exe that performs other things, have look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/07/14/edm-tools-options-part-4-of-4.aspx) but it might be out of date. Another option would be to create your own T4 file that you could launch with `TextTransform.exe`. It would be able to take a table list as parameter and edit the EDMX file using Linq2SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers, you gave me multiple choices.